# Java: equivalent to C's strnicmp? (both startsWith and ignoreCase)

Tags: java, string

```
 String string1 = "abCdefGhijklMnopQrstuvwYz";
 String string2 = "ABC";
```

I had been using string1.startsWith(string2), which would return false in the above example, but now I need to ignore case sensitivity, and there is not a String.startsWithIgnoreCase().

Besides doing

```
 string1.toLowerCase.startsWith(string2.toLowerCase());
```

is there an efficient way to see if string1 starts with string2 in a case-insensitive way?

Comment: thanks for the anonymous "-1", whoever gave it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`regionMatches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches%28boolean,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) method has a case sensitive parameter.

Comment: cool, thanks! I just noticed http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/CaseinsensitivecheckifaStringstartswithaspecifiedprefix.htm which seems to take this approach.

Answer (score 7):

Use StringUtils library.

```
    StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase("abCdefGhijklMnopQrstuvwYz", "ABC"); // true
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#startsWithIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
string2.equalsIgnoreCase(string1.substring(0, string2.length())
```

Comment: Sorry but needs
`string1.length() > string2.length() && string2.equalsIgnoreCase(string1.substring(0, string2.length()))` to be correct

Comment: @HamzehSoboh, correct (almost). Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't take into account that `string1.substring(0, string2.length())` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `string1.length() < string2.length()`. But condition should be `string1.length() >= string2.length()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.toLowerCase().startsWith(string2.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: I might point out this isn't a particularly helpful answer - I suggest expanding on your answers in a little more detail!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String s, String w)
    {
        if (w==null)
            return true;

        if (s==null || s.length()<w.length())
            return false;

        for (int i=0;i<w.length();i++)
        {
            char c1=s.charAt(i);
            char c2=w.charAt(i);
            if (c1!=c2)
            {
                if (c1<=127)
                    c1=Character.toLowerCase(c1);
                if (c2<=127)
                    c2=Character.toLowerCase(c2);
                if (c1!=c2)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

By the way are you sure you need efficiency here?

Comment: Am I sure I need it: no. But I may in the future, in which case I want to know an alternative.

Your code snippet looks like it is from java2s (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/StartsWithIgnoreCase.htm), please cite sources, and this does not handle Unicode.

Comment: Of course it is taken from a link. I can cite the original link, I can also write 15 different versions of it just to show up I'm able to do it :) But wasting so much time for a quite useless question seemed too much.. then __chars__ on JDK are unicode, so it should handle unicode, read documentation before spending time searching if a simple snippet is taken somewhere.